# the if statement condition logic

Tags: javascript

I am in need of help in this script. I am trying to write a program, where each array element is assign to a "point". I concated all the arrays and assigned it to a variable. The array runs through an if statement to tally up the score.

For this instance, I am trying to get a total of 6. However, when I run the program I am getting "2" rather than "6" in the console log. How should I write my if condition to get the result of 6?

```js
var zero = [1,2,3,5,7]; // 0
var one = [0,4,6,9]; // 1
var two = 8; //2




function calculate(){
  
 var NUMBERS = zero.concat(one,two);
  
  var TOTAL = 0; // 6
  
  for(var i = 0;  i < NUMBERS.length;  i++){
   if(NUMBERS[i] === one[i]){
        TOTAL += 1;
    }else if(NUMBERS[i] == two){
        TOTAL +=2;
    }else {
      TOTAL += 0;
    }
    
  }
  
  console.log(TOTAL);
}

calculate();
```

Comment: why do you want total of 6?? whats the logic?

Comment: Walk through it in the debugger built into your browser and look at the values of your variables as you step through the code. (If you don't know how to do that, the first thing to do is to learn how to do that. :-) ) The indexes in `NUMBERS` are not the same as the indexes in `one`, and, `TOTAL += 0` is a no-op (does nothing).

Comment: Finally: As near as I can make out the logic (count 1 for every entry in `NUMBERS` that appears in `one` and 2 for every entry in `NUMBERS` that equals `two`), you'd get 7, not 6. `NUMBERS` is `[1,2,4,5,7,0,4,6,9,8]`. So 1 each for `4,0,4,6,9` is 5 plus 2 for `8` is 7.

Comment: @Reddy Why do I want it to be 6? lol It's what I want out of this program. Just trying to learn.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—glad you worked that out, as implemented in the OP I got 0.

Comment: @Recon sorry for my English, I wanted to ask you how do you say that the output must be 6. Whats the logic? There are 2 kinds of logic one is how you manipulate a problem in your mind and arrive at a solution. Second is how you make the program get you the desired result. I want to know the first logic so that I can help you out in the second programming logic

Comment: @Reddy: Your original comment was perfectly clear, the problem wasn't at your end.

Answer (score 1):

This will only match if the value in NUMBERS[i] is in the same position of the array one.

```
if(NUMBERS[i] === one[i]){
```

Change it to this:

```
if (one.indexOf(NUMBERS[i]) !== -1){
```

to test for the presence of NUMBERS[i] in one.

Also, you have a four in both the zero and one array.

As @TJCrowder mentioned - the answer is seven.

You can omit:

```
TOTAL += 0
```

Adding zero doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.